# Нужно найти все возможные варианты прочтения строки

Tags: javascript

```
var s = 'neseswnnew'; ///есть строка
var d = ['e','n','s','w'];//есть возможные варианты
var da = ['ne','nw','sw','se'];// и такие
```

нужно найти все возможные варианты прочтения строки

например

- 1 - news
- 2 - ne-s-e-s-w-n-n-w
- 3 - n-e-se-se-n-nw
- 4 - ne-e-s-e-se-n-w
- и т.д.

Comment: не очень понятно, что хочется найти. распишите, почему подходит 'n-e-w-s' (ведь такая подстрока не встречается). кроме того, буквы ['e', 'n', 's', 'w'] в s идут в порядке 'n-e-s-e-s-w-e-w'. как вы собрали 'n-e-w-s'??? дайте подробное определение, что такое 'варианты прочтения строки'.

Comment: n-e-w-s подходит так как в массиве d есть соответсвующие символы,это можно считать одни из вариантов прочтения
так же строку можно прочитать как ne -se-s-w-n-e,так как ne и se есть в массиве da, а остальные символы есть в массиве d
еще вариант n-e-se-sw-n-ne-w, так как n,e,w - есть в массиве d,а se,sw,ne - есть в массиве da

Comment: давайте тогда определение чтения. в тексте 's' идет до 'w', а после первой 'w' нет символов 's'. 'news' ну никак не получается, если читаем слева на право. правильно ли я понимаю, что у вас чтение в любую сторону и направление можем менять когда захотим? а может читать можно рандомно?